# Matching blank lines with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string that I'm trying to split into chunks based on blank lines.

Given a string `s`, I thought I could do this:

```
re.split('(?m)^\s*$', s)
```

This works in some cases:

```
>>> s = 'foo\nbar\n \nbaz'
>>> re.split('(?m)^\s*$', s)
['foo\nbar\n', '\nbaz']
```

But it doesn't work if the line is completely empty:

```
>>> s = 'foo\nbar\n\nbaz'
>>> re.split('(?m)^\s*$', s)
['foo\nbar\n\nbaz']
```

What am I doing wrong?

[python 2.5; no difference if I compile `'^\s*$'` with `re.MULTILINE` and use the compiled expression instead]

Comment: Is the \s there because these lines might or might not contain whitespace characters?

Comment: can you show some input and your output examples?

Comment: Looks like this functions as designed. From http://docs.python.org/library/re.html : "split will never split a string on an empty pattern match". For a working version, see Glenn Maynard's answer ('\n\s*\n'), but note his warning about handling multiple empty/whitespace lines. You could try building something around re.finditer instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
re.split('\n\s*\n', s)
```

The problem is that "$ *^" actually only matches "spaces (if any) that are alone on a line"--not the newlines themselves.  This leaves the delimiter empty when there's nothing on the line, which doesn't make sense.

This version also gets rid of the delimiting newlines themselves, which is probably what you want.  Otherwise, you'll have the newlines stuck to the beginning and end of each split part.

Treating multiple consecutive blank lines as defining an empty block ("abc\n\n\ndef" -> ["abc", "", "def"]) is trickier...

Comment: However, it leaves even-numbered empty lines at the beginning of their chunks, which might not be desired.

Comment: Funny how your mind can get stuck in a rut.. I needed multiline for some other matching, and so it seemed obvious to use it here.  So much for "obvious".  I will keep Zac's answer as accepted because he quoted my exact situation from the docs, but your answer is very helpful too!

Comment: I gave an explanation and a solution; he didn't.

Comment: D'oh!  Well, that's what I get for rushing to answer.  I actually think that your alternate example here is equivalent to your first; \s includes \n, after all.  In other words, I don't think eswald is right.  Also this answer will not "deal" with terminating newlines in the string to be split, if that matters.  But it's better than my "give up and go home" approach.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Somehow "\s*" became " *" while I was editing.  I've fixed the answer; that simplifies it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The re library can split on one or more empty lines !  An empty line is a string that consists of zero or more whitespaces, starts at the start of the line and ends at the end of a line. Special character '$' matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline (excerpt from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)). That's why we need to add a special character '\s*' for the line break. Everything is possible :-)

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "foo\n   \n    \n    \nbar\n"
>>> re.split("(?m)^\s*$\s*", text)
['foo\n', 'bar\n']
```

The same regex works with windows style line breaks.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "foo\r\n       \r\n     \r\n   \r\nbar\r\n"
>>> re.split("(?m)^\s*$\s*", text)
['foo\r\n', 'bar\r\n']
```

Comment: To remove trailing line breaks you have to add `\s*` before `^` as follow: `re.split("(?m)\s*^\s*$\s*", text)`

Comment: `text = "foo\n   \n    \n    \nbar\n"` theres no empty lines

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
blank=''
with open('fu.txt') as txt:
    txt=txt.read().split('\n') 
    for line in txt:
        if line is blank: print('blank')
        else: print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> s = 'foo\nbar\n\nbaz'
>>> re.split('\n\s*\n',s)
['foo\nbar', 'baz']

>>> s = 'foo\nbar\n \nbaz'
>>> re.split('\n\s*\n',s)
['foo\nbar', 'baz']

>>> s = 'foo\nbar\n\t\nbaz'
>>> re.split('\n\s*\n',s)
['foo\nbar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score -3):

What you're doing wrong is using regular expressions. What is wrong with ('Some\ntext.').split('\n')?

Comment: He wants to match blank lines that may have whitespace.  Splitting on "\n" will split every line apart.  Splittong on "\n\n" (which is probably what you meant) won't work on blank lines with whitespace on them.

Comment: because that doesn't split the input where he asked for.  He wants to separate groups of text by multiple newlines.  IE two lines containing text, separated by a single newline are not separated, but if separated by two (or presumably more) newlines, with only whitespace on any blank lines, should be separate.

Comment: So don't say "blank" if you don't mean "blank."